# Finding dual of matrix algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, dual-spaces, algebras, coalgebras

Consider $A=M_n(K)$, the algebra of matrices over the field $K$. Let $\{e_{ij}\}$ be the standard basis for $A$ and $\{X_{ij}\}$ be the basis of $A^*$ dual to $\{e_{ij}\}$.

 I need to find the operations on $A^*$, that is, show that comultiplication $\Delta = (m_A)^*$ is given by
$$\Delta(X_{ij})=\sum_{k=1}^n X_{ik} \otimes X_{kj}$$
and that counit $\epsilon=(u_A)^*$ is given by
$$\epsilon(X_{ij})=\delta_{ij}.$$
By this, it follows that $A^*$ is the same as the matrix coalgebra.

 How can I find these formulas for the operations on $A^*$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the definition of the comultiplication on the dual, we have that
$$\Delta(X_{ij})(e_{kl},e_{mn})=X_{ij}(e_{kl}e_{mn})=\delta_{lm}\delta_{ik}\delta_{nj}.$$
To show your first relation, let us write
$$\Delta(X_{ij})=\sum_{klmn}a_{klmn}X_{kl}\otimes X_{mn}.$$
Then the first equation reads at
$$a_{klmn}=\delta_{lm}\delta_{ik}\delta_{nj}$$
Inserting this relation yields
$$\Delta(X_{ij})=\sum_{l}X_{il}\otimes X_{lj},$$
as desired.

Similarly, the counit is defined so that $$\epsilon(X_{ij})=X_{ij}(u_A)=X_{ij}(I)=\delta_{ij},$$ where here $I$ is the identity matrix.